# possible for users to entry their email address and get sent an email back to them. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

just wondering if it is even possible to try and send an email to a user after they have entered their email address. sorry, there is little code, honestly wouldn't even know where to start. (it's kinda like when u enter your email in a dodgy website and u get spam emails afterward). wondering even if you could send me in the right direction at all.thanks

```
from tkinter import *

frame4 = tk.Tk()

def email_customer ():

    import smtplib




confirmBtn = tk.Button(frame4, text="Confirm order",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',20) )
confirmBtn.place(x= 590, y = 570)

    
EmailEntry = tk.Entry(frame4, text="enter email",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',20))
EmailEntry.place (x= 425, y= 570)
  
username = '*****@gmail.com'
password = '********'


sender_email = '*****@mail.com'
rec_email = EmailEntry.get()
password = '*******'
message = "Hey, this was sent using python"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, rec_email, message)
    


def email_appears():
    EmailEntry = tk.Entry(frame4, text="enter email",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',20))
    EmailEntry.place (x= 425, y= 570)
    EmailEntry.get()
    
    confirmBtn = tk.Button(frame4, text="Confirm order",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',20))
    confirmBtn.place(x= 590, y = 570)
    

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame4, text='click to confirm', command = email_appears, bg = '#F0EAD6',font=('Arial',16) )
c1. place (x= 600, y= 500)

frame4.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this help? https://realpython.com/python-send-email/

Comment: Also, this is not tkinter, related.

Comment: have tried for the last 2 hours, doesn't look like anything is working. unfortunately. @BrianZhang. thanks though

Comment: If that was your real password in the code, change the password ASAP.

Comment: Also, learn about event driven programming.

Comment: no fake account sorry for the scare.